# why does my code not show both frame.add?

Tags: java, swing

the script works fine for dragging around one image but if I try to get two of them going at once it acts as if the class can only be called once?  here is the code where i am adding two imageicons , but only one is showing:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

public class TestMouseDrag {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestMouseDrag();
}

public TestMouseDrag() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            frame.add(new DragMyIcon("C:\\Users\\anon\\Desktop\\Hobbit.png")).setLocation(100, 100);
            frame.add(new DragMyIcon("C:\\Users\\anon\\Desktop\\alien.png")).setLocation(100, 100)
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(700,700);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class DragMyIcon extends JPanel {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 172L;
    private JLabel label;

    public DragMyIcon(String path) {
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon icon = null;

        icon = new ImageIcon(path);

        label = new JLabel(icon);
        label.setBounds(0,0,100, 100);

        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        add(label);

        MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
        label.addMouseListener(handler);
        label.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

    }

}

protected class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    private boolean active = false;
    private int xDisp;
    private int yDisp;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        active = true;
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();

        xDisp = e.getPoint().x - label.getLocation().x;
        yDisp = e.getPoint().y - label.getLocation().y;

        label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        active = false;
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
        label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (active) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
            Point point = e.getPoint();
            label.setLocation(point.x - xDisp, point.y - yDisp);
            label.invalidate();
            label.repaint();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}}
```

Comment: You understand that `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default and that it will only allow a single component to reside within any one of the 5 available slots.  This means by adding your second image, you are effectively removing the first.  Also, try resizing the window after you've dragged one the labels...

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not respect the layout managers that it is using -- BorderLayout. When you add a component to a BorderLayout using container without specifying position, it is placed by default BorderLayout.CENTER and covers anything added previously.

Solution: read up on the layout managers including BorderLayout to see how to use them. 
Also, you're probably better off not adding two DragMyIcon objects, but rather changing DragMyIcon so that it allows for multiple JLabels.